# Do child classes inherit Lombok annotations?

Tags: java, spring-boot, lombok

Suppose I have a `Building` class:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Building {

  @Id
  private Long buildingId;

  private String buildingName;

  private Integer buildingStoreys;

  private String buildingAddress; 

}
```

and I extend `Building` class to create a `House` class:

```
public class House extends Building {
  
  private Integer numberOfRooms;

  private Integer numberOfBathrooms;
  
  private String houseType;
}
```

Do I need to add `@Data` and `@NoArgsConstructor` annotations to `House` class explicitly in order to generate getter, setter and constructor?

I figured that I should add the annotations since they generate code for all the methods in the class it is annotated in but I don't think this applies to the child classes as well.

Comment: No, lombok annotations don't have `@Inherited`, so they don't get inherited. See [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/g/project-lombok/c/vV-LpfHZNp4).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll have to add the annotations in the child class explicitly.